# How can I learn to produce "harsh voice"

Tags: phonetics

I'd like to work on my ability to identify creaky and harsh voice. Creaky voice is not a huge problem - I already have a reasonable idea of what that sounds like and there are a million YT videos explaining how it's done. Harsh voice is another matter though. I have found abstract descriptions of it, but very little in the way of examples or practical how-tos. Can anyone point me to anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might look at "The valves of the throat and their functioning in tone, vocal register and stress: Laryngoscopic case studies", Edmonson & Esling (2006).
The book *Voice quality: the laryngeal articulator model* by Esling, Moisik, Benner & Crevier-Buchman (2019) includes harsh voice in their account of the larynx as an articulator. It includes some online videos and photos, available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Te5DhQ6NApJoDXJOePR5c_HUOBLJsec). [Chapter 2](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yoo11qihUInavCUBrlaXAaquoPVK0V__) is probably the most relevant to your interest, especially the demo video of [harsh voice](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yoo11qihUInavCUBrlaXAaquoPVK0V__) and [harsh voiced laughter](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yoo11qihUInavCUBrlaXAaquoPVK0V__). There are, additionally, demos of laryngeal sound types that you can compare harsh voice with. I will say that the samples do not sound like Bor Dinka "hard" voice in my experience, which is said to be harsh voice, but individual variation is not surprising.

Comment: Well that will keep me busy for a while... Thanks once again.